# nginx location with equal AND not equal regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following code which fires on with a *.m3u8 file is in the url.

Example URL: http://example.com/live/username/password/stream.m3u8

```
location ~ [^/]\.m3u8(/|$)(?!token$) {
    expires 10s;
    resolver            1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout    5s;
    proxy_pass http://origin_server;
    proxy_redirect http://1.2.3.4 http://lb_server.example.com;
}
```

It matches the m3u8 file ext but I need it to NOT use this 'location' if the url looks like *.m3u8?toek=blah_blah

I cannot seem to get it to work for the life of me.

Comment: ^(?!.*?token=).*m3u8.*$ works on regex101.com which is really confusing :(

Comment: It seems you're forgetting that locations in NGINX match against normalized URLs, without query parameters.

Comment: How do you want to process URIs containing the `token` argument?

Comment: Comments without '?token=' would be handled by the defualt 'location /' :D

Comment: @DanilaVershinin - I'm new to NGINX so I was unaware of that fact.